# Finding the number of items which are associated to a specified set of related items

Tags: mysql

I have a table, `Transactions`, containing this data:

```
+------+---------+
|  id  |  item   |
+------+---------+
| 1    |    A    |
| 1    |    B    |
| 2    |    A    |
| 2    |    D    |
| 3    |    C    |
| 3    |    D    |
| 4    |    E    |
| 4    |    C    |
| 5    |    A    |
| 5    |    B    |
| 5    |    C    |
+------+---------+
```

How would I find the number of transactions that contain a specified set of items?

For example, the number of transactions that contain items A and B is two, because only transactions 1 and 5 contain both of those items.

Comment: what is the input for your problem? search how many transaction has the same items as `id = 1` or find how many transaction has items `A and B` ? Because in case you search `id = 5` you will find 3 items

Comment: thanks for helping, the input is items A and B, so any transaction having booth items A and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure what will be your input, but to solve your question this will do

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5b83/6)**

This will count transactions with both items `A` and `B`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (             
      SELECT id, count(*)
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY `id`
      HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN  `item` = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0
         AND COUNT( CASE WHEN  `item` = 'B' THEN 1 END) > 0
      ) T
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| count(*) |
|----------|
|        2 |
```

**NOTE**

The `count(*)` in the subquery is optional, was just add it for debug to have a visual feedaback of that subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this, though not tested:

```
SELECT A.id, count(A.item) AS cntA, count(B.item) AS cntB
FROM table AS A
LEFT JOIN table AS B
   ON (A.item = B.item) AND (A.id <> B.id)
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING cntA = cntB
```

Self join the table on different IDs having the same items, and compare the count of items. If the count is the same, then the two IDs have the same items.

Comment: This work for pairs. But transaction_id 5 has three elements, so I guess OP may need a broad solution.

Comment: but it joins all of the items and counts them (did have it as an inner join by mistake, though) and compares the counts. doesn't matter how many or few there are - it's just comparing counts.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter, and probably a bit faster:

```
SELECT  id
    FROM  Transactions
    WHERE  item IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY  id
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT item) = 2
```